# iOS UIWebView won´t load

Tags: ios

I made a simple `UIWebView` in my storyboard.

What happens now is that when the start screen appears the app stops there.

Is anything wrong with my code?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];   
}

@end
```

and my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ist attempt try

```
 NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com";
```

change into

```
 NSString * fullURL = @"http://www.google.com";
```

if it is not work choice no 2

```
_webView.delegate = self;
```

add this new method in your class

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
```

I hope you have connected webView object with its outlet in Interface builder?

if you need more assistance check this [tutorial](http://hayageek.com/uiwebview-uiwebviewdelegate-tutorial/)

Comment: put break point in viewcontoller stating and check your method is called or not

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have not added your delegate and the methods try changing:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

TO

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

and then either in your storyboard link your webView to the delegate or in your code add this line `[_webView setDelegate:self];` just about your `loadRequest:` call.

When implementing a `UIWebView` you need to also add `UIWebViewDelegate` to the interface. This will allow you then to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods which are:

```
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
- webViewDidStartLoad:
- webViewDidFinishLoad:
- webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

Have a read of the Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) for a better description of what these methods do and how they work.